# Java Android If Else Break Having Issue Troubleshooting

Tags: java, android, if-statement

So this is a function I  created.

As you can see this will read for files searching for `filename` and then it reads for `--TEMPERATURE UP--`.

Problem is not every `filename` has a `--TEMPERATURE UP--` and

I tried using an else statement but if I remove the `break` from the else statement, for `filename` without `--TEMPERATURE UP--` the whole app will crash

But if I add a `break` statement in the else statement, every `filename` will run the else statement which even if they contains `--TEMPERATURE UP--`

I have also tried to do a simple else statement without the `!line.equals("--TEMPERATURE UP--")` but it's still the same.

Either I have to add `break` at the else to run the `else` code which will not run the `if` code OR I remove the `break` which run the `if` code but unable to run the `else` code as it will crash.

Please advise on how I should go about changing my codes such that when it reads   `--TEMPERATURE UP--` it will run the `if` code, otherwise it will run the `else` code.

Thanks alot.

```
public void tempUp() {
    SharedPreferences sharedTest = getSharedPreferences("MySharedTest", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String filename = sharedTest.getString("filename", " ");
    Log.d("File readed: ", filename);
    File dir = new File(path);
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    for (File f : files) {
        if (f.isFile()) {
            BufferedReader inputStream = null;
            try {
                inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
                String lineToRead = filename;
                String CurrentLine;
                while ((CurrentLine = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (CurrentLine.equals(lineToRead)) {
                        try
                        {
                            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
                            String line = reader.readLine();
                            while(line !=null)
                            {
                                line = reader.readLine();
                                if(line.equals("--TEMPERATURE UP--"))
                                {
                                    final String ms = reader.readLine();
                                    Log.d("temp up: ", ms);
                                    new Thread(new Runnable()
                                    {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run()
                                        {
                                            String message = "\u000704NTX" + ms + "\r";
                                            byte[] byte_array = message.getBytes();

                                            try
                                            {
                                                SharedPreferences prefx = getSharedPreferences("Device_Data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                                String device_ip = prefx.getString("local_ip", " ");
                                                String host = device_ip;
                                                Socket socket = new Socket(host, 8070);
                                                DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                                                out.write(byte_array);
                                                out.flush();
                                            }
                                            catch (Exception e)
                                            {
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }).start();
                                    break;
                                }

                                else if (!line.equals("--TEMPERATURE UP--"))
                                {
                                    Toast.makeText(TestScreen.this, "There is no Temperature Display for this profile.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    break;
                                }

                                }


                        }
                        catch (IOException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }



                    }

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Updated:

```
                    try
                    {
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
                        String line = reader.readLine();
                        boolean hasTempDisplayProfile = false;
                        while((line = reader.readLine()) !=null)
                        {

                            if(line.equals("--TEMPERATURE UP--")) {
                                hasTempDisplayProfile = true;
                                final String ms = reader.readLine();
                                Log.d("temp up: ", ms);
                                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        String message = "\u000704NTX" + ms + "\r";
                                        byte[] byte_array = message.getBytes();

                                        try {
                                            SharedPreferences prefx = getSharedPreferences("Device_Data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                            String device_ip = prefx.getString("local_ip", " ");
                                            String host = device_ip;
                                            Socket socket = new Socket(host, 8070);
                                            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                                            out.write(byte_array);
                                            out.flush();
                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                        }
                                    }
                                }).start();
                                break;
                            }

                            }

                        if (hasTempDisplayProfile){
                            Toast.makeText(TestScreen.this, "There is no Temperature Display for this profile.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Comment: Please add a clear description of what your code is supposed to be doing.

Comment: Maybe you should print out the line? The if statement isn't broken...

Comment: You inner `while` is breaking no matter what condition, so why have a `while`?

Comment: Basically it a thread if it reads `--TEMPERATURE UP--`, if not I just want to toast a message. thats all. @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Also, why are you making two BufferedReaders of the same file anyway?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I removed the inner while but I leave the 2 break statement there but I still face the same issue

Comment: @cricket_007 I actually didnt have an else before, everything was working , then I try to add an else today because I realize some files does not contain `--TEMPERATURE UP--` and then I keep encountering problems while implementing a toast for the files without `--TEMPERATURE UP--`

Comment: Again, might be useful for you to add breakpoints to your code and debug it... Especially if you aren't going to provide the input file here as part of a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current implementation is:

```
while(readLine) {
   if (line.equal("--TEMPERATURE UP--") {
     // process
   } else {
     // Toast message
   }
}
```

So do you see the problem now? The problem is your are testing again `--TEMPERATURE UP--` for every line and show Toast every time the line is not match.

It's wrong.

What you want is to check if the whole file does not contain the `--TEMPERATURE UP--`, if so, then show the toast.

So the correct implementation would involving a flag:

```
boolean hasTempDisplayProfile = false;
while(readLine) {
   if (line.equal("--TEMPERATURE UP--") {
     // process
     hasTempDisplayProfile = true;
   }
}

if (!hasTempDisplayProfile) {
  // Toast message
}
```

**Edit**
Your code has another serious flaw:

```
String line = reader.readLine();
while(line !=null){
    line = reader.readLine();
     ... your process ...
}
```

In this code, you read a line. Then check for line not equals null in the `while`. The problem is you did not use that line but process to read another `line = reader.readLine()`. It will throw `NullPointerException` when you reach end of file.

Change to this:

```
String line;
while((line = reader.readLine()) !=null){
     // Do not read new line here. Just process with "line"
}
```

By the way, your code need improvement. It now has too much indentation, which is very frustrate to read. You can try:

1. Break your function into smaller modules
2. Use fail-fast. That is instead of wrap your code if the condition hold `true`, try to return when `false`. For example your:

   ```
     for (File f: files) {
         if (f.isFile()) {
            // Your process
         }
     }
   ```

should be changed to:

```
      for (File f: files) {
         if (!f.isFile()) {
            continue;
         }
         // Your process
      }
```

It reduces one level of indentation.

Comment: Hi can you advise me on where to break for the if else statement, I have changed added the boolean as advise but whenever I try to run those profile without the `--TEMPERATURE UP--` it will still crash and the error points towards `(line.equal("--TEMPERATURE UP--")` So I was thinking maybe my break is wrong . Currently I place 2 break at both the if and else

Comment: do you have any `break` in `if (hasTempDisplayProfile) {` ? Could you capture screenshot of your code now and share me?

Comment: Hi please refresh the page and check the question I have added my current codes under `Updated:`

Comment: And please re-read my answer, the block `if (!hasTempDisplayProfile)` is placed outside the `while` loop.

Comment: Hi , ok I have updated according to your edited answer and I have tried placing `if (!hasTempDisplayProfile)` in and out of the while loop. Both have the same results. What happens now is if the file does not have `--TEMPERATURE UP--`, nothing happen no error no nothing, but if the file has `--TEMPERATURE UP--`, it still run the process but at the same time it  does the toast inside `if (!hasTempDisplayProfile)`  as well

Comment: Post your updated code, where the `if (! hasTempDisplayProfile)` is outside the `while`

Comment: Done, please refresh the page and check

Comment: Please check that the correct is `if (! hasTempDisplayProfile)`, and you don't need `break;` in that if block. You can safely remove it

Comment: Thank you so much ! Thanks for your time to troubleshoot for me. Sorry if my code is messy, kind of new to android

Comment: You're welcome! Consider my suggestion on reduce level of indentation. It's hard to read and maintain

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170739/discussion-between-kelvin-jigsawing-and-mnh-quyt-nguyn).